# How to take advantage of ARMv7s on iPhone 5 in Objective-C iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

I am wondering how to actually take advantage of the ARMv7s architecture for iPhone 5?

Are there specific instructions in Objective-C that will only work with this architecture, or is there a flag to force it to use armv7s and run faster?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your project's build architectures to "armv7" and "armv7s" (which should be the default for new projects), as described in the [App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html). The compiler will take care of choosing the optimal instructions to take advantage of the `armv7s` profile.

Comment: Yes defaults are set to armv7 and armv7s. So there is nothing that you need to do to take advantage of it? It just simply works and theoretically will run faster?

Comment: Yes, you don't need to do anything. Supported devices will load the `armv7s` version.